# Powershell - Delete specific word from a text file

Tags: powershell

I tried to search on google but I did not find anything about it,
Simply I have a .CSV file that contains for example this,

APPNAME,Status OK,Ping OK 
APPNAME2,Status OK,Ping FAIL

There are multiple lines, all i need is to delete "Status" and "PING" from the text file so that the output will be like this

APPNAME, OK, OK 
APPNAME2, OK, FAIL

Is that possible ? If so thank you for your reply.

Comment: Sure it's possible. You import the CSV file with [Import-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) with all the headers. But when you export the data with [Export-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) you use [Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) to limit the Export to the desired columns. Please always read the complete help including the examples.

Comment: Could you please help me with the code ? I am a newbie to Powershell.

Comment: Did you read all the help topics for the cmdlets? If yes - don't you have an idea how to start? It does not have to be perfect but I'd like to see at least something.  ;-) You should update your question with the code you have. We might be able to improve it then.